# sIFR links lose focus in Firefox 3.6 after scrolling

Tags: sifr, sifr3, firefox3.6

I've noticed this issue in previous versions of Firefox whereby after scrolling sIFR links become inactive and need to be clicked in order to become links again. The fix for this was fairly straightforward and just required you to add 'fixFocus: true' in the sIFR config.

Unfortunately when I upgraded to Firefox 3.6 this fix no longer works. I'm just wondering if anyone else has come across this and know if there's a workaround. We use sIFR links in loads of our sites so this is a pretty bad bug!

Thanks in advance if anyone can help

***update - it seems like it's the addition of using the wmode: 'transparent' - if i take this out the fix focus works again. Still a problem though as most of our links need to be transparent**

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it's a browser issue, and a rather old one by now. There's no better workaround available in sIFR.

Answer (score 0):

A trick to make the sIFR links work fine in firefox when having the wmode set to transparent, is to add that CSS code to the class that is being replaced :

```
.fontname:hover {background-position:0% 100%;}
```

In this example, fontname is the CSS class that determines which tags are replaced.